# Sessions in Codeigniter with PHP7

Tags: codeigniter, session, php-7

The Problem is simple. If i use

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->session->sess_regenerate(true);
```

i get an error:

```
Message:  session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active
Filename: Session/Session.php
Line Number: 625
```

That only happens with PHP 7 and works with 5.6.
I figured that the parameter in the regenerate function is set to destroy the old session data when regenerating. When i leave out the sess_destroy() i don't get an error, but the session data is not destroyed and i can't log the user out.

Comment: i'm using Codeigniter version 3.03

Comment: Use the newer version 3.0.4 https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/79b8a086187f199bb708bd56477850fbf1dd9e91

Comment: @Chris Did you find any valid answer for this question?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really remember. I haven't used CI or PHP for years. I actually switched to Laravel after CI and had a much better experience. Nowadays it's just JS all the way :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `ob_start()` before session library. And before session destroying code add `ob_flush()` and after that line set `ob_clean()`

---

And set this `$this->session->sess_regenerate(true);` to `FALSE`.  `ob_flush` and `ob_clean` will do that perfectly.